# How to implement functional interface for class by lambda?

Tags: kotlin, functional-interface

I have `Decorator` interface:

```kotlin
fun interface Decorator {
    decorate(text: String): String
}
```

And I want to implement it for class `Padded` by lambda like this:

```kotlin
class Padded(padding: String) : Decorator {
    text -> "$padding $text $padding"
}
```

I don't want to write method signature, introduce another class wrapper, or replace class with higher-order function. How can I do it?

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to write out the method signature? Usually your IDE will offer to do it for you, anyway.

Comment: @ndc85430 because this would be longer and wouldn't utilize benefits from using functional interface. Using IDE for boilerplate code is off-topic.

Comment: @MaxSmirnov sometimes longer is better. But here the regular override is almost as short - at least the same number of lines. What exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be implemented with delegate pattern.

```kotlin
class Padded(padding: String) : Decorator by (Decorator {
    text -> "$padding $text $padding"
})
```

Comment: What's the point, though? I believe this is less readable to most people, and it's more code than the function approach I suggested, and arguably as much code as the standard override. Also, you're creating 2 objects when you instantiate the `Padded` class.

Comment: It is less readable, it is longer, and it is slower, but point is not using it, but investigating of Kotlin possibilities. I was looking for implementation with class, and this is it.

Comment: If you don't care about readability, length of code and speed, it's probably worth putting that in the question. Those are normally the criteria by which people judge code.

Comment: @mattfreake my question was "how to IMPLEMENT lambda with class". Where I am asking for readable and fast code? Where I am asking for implementation with function? Where I am asking for judgement and code review? I am straightforward asking for implementation, while you trying to be as much SO meme as possible by posting unrelated answers and comments.

Answer (score 3):

The point of using functional interfaces is to be able to provide a lambda in places where an *instance* of such interface is required, instead of instantiating a class that implements that interface (or creating an anonymous object implementing it). Functional interfaces don't help with implementing interfaces in class declarations.

What you could do is declare a `Padded` function, which returns an instance of `Decorator` using a lambda:

```kotlin
fun Padded(padding: String) = Decorator { "$padding $it $padding" }
```

But if you want a class, you'll have to implement the function explicitly:

```kotlin
class Padded(padding: String) : Decorator {
    override fun decorate(text: String) = "$padding $text $padding"
}
```

which is honestly the same number of lines as the syntax you were looking for, and very clear to everyone.

Comment: thanks for working example, but I am asking for code with `class`. I know that it can be implemented like `Padded : DecoratorWrap(Decorator { ... })` and `class Decorator(d: Decorator) : Decorator by d`, that is why I am asking for more elegant version with class, and not function.

Comment: *but I am asking for code with class* - the first paragraph in my answer is to explain that you won't get any benefits or difference from implementing a `fun interface` vs a regular `interface` in a `class` declaration. There is no special syntax for implementing functional interfaces with `class` declarations (at least to my knowledge), but that is not what they are for anyway IMO

Comment: I understand that they aren't designed for this, but this is just a closure and it should be the way implement it with class. I figured out how, and posted code below. Again, thanks for pointing at fun interface purpose, but that wasn't the point of my question.